# How to get a color of a feature?

Tags: wfs, getfeature

[image]

My code:

```
var inter = new ol.interaction.Select();
inter.getFeatures().on('add', function(event) {
var properties = event.element.getProperties();     
var coordinates = event.element.getGeometry().getCoordinates(); 
**var featureId = event.element.getProperties();**
```

I want to can do something like that --> event.element.getProperties().getColor or getValue...Finally, I want to get the green color  in this case

```
featureId=green
```

Answer (score 1):

WFS features don't have a colour in general, they represent the raw data that is used to draw the map. So somewhere in your set up there is some styling code that converts a features attributes into a colour. It might be in your leaflet code if you are dealing with just a WFS or it might be on the WMS if that is where your map comes from.

That may be a simple as an attribute `colour` which might equal `green` but more likely it is something like:

```
if "type" == 'manhole' then colour feature green.
```

Comment: Yes, the style is in my set up, I have point reds and green,I am working with WFS. Just I want get to get a color of a feature when click the point. I need a solution to distinguish between one color and another.

Answer (score -1):

I have used in the function that returns the style:

```
feature.setProperties({'color':'green'});
feature.setProperties({'color':'red'});
```

Then, you can call it that way:

```
var properties = event.element.getProperties();
var color =properties.color;
```

Comment: This will not return the current color value, but a property created by yourself. This will not work for features imported automatically, for example.